# How to restore file from root Trash

Tags: trash

I am with Linux Mint, I delete a file with **caja**, it is the file manager for **Mate** Desktop. Because **caja** is open as **root**, now the file which I delete is on the root Trash...

I try as David Yockey to say,

[image]

The First I to try to look is the File which delete **rescuee.img** but to say , Das Argument ist ungültig - Argument is invalid and keine Berechtigung - Not authority..

With the seconds, **junk_file**, I to come similar...

My question, how can restore this file?

can someone help me, thanks!

Comment: The invalid argument listings correspond to `find` trying to search particular directories that it can't access. It looks like it found `rescuee.img` in the directory `/media/.../cff201e8-c3bc-4517-95d9-862c547f26f2/.Trash-0/files/`. It's not in that directory, is it?

Comment: yes, now to try  again the file to rescue and it belongs to them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in `/root/.local/share/Trash/files`. I ran Caja as root, created a file in `/root`, deleted it, poked around a bit, and found it in that folder. I was then able to cut & paste it from there back into `/root`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!, on my folder `share` I have not a `Trash` folder..

Comment: I'd try a bit of detective work, then... In Caja running as root, create a file with a unique name like `junk_file` and then delete it. Then, log into a root terminal, run `find / -name junk_file`, and see where it landed. If it's found, you can get it back from there (you should be able to view that location in Caja as well). If not, I'd conclude that your Caja, at least when running as root, is immediately deleting files rather than moving them to a trash directory.

Comment: Thanks, now I will new Edit my question...

Comment: Because Now rescue again my file with `ddrescue`, not to need my old file.            I wish your a nice Day!

Answer (score 1):

I don't find this accepted answer entirely satisfactory: files or directories which are sent to Trash have their original location somehow recorded with them so that it is possible to restore them without necessarily knowing that original location.

As a non-root user you can usually use your file explorer, Nemo in my case (OS Linux Mint 18.3), to restore, by clicking Trash and then finding the restore command in the context menu (right-click) of the file in question.

When you run Nemo as root (`gksudo nemo`) however, this doesn't work: the Trash bounces your focus away, giving you a "no access" message, and doesn't display its contents properly.

But there is a solution which I found: install the `trash-cli` package.

One of the commands there is `restore-trash`, incidentally wrongly documented as `trash-restore(1)` in the `man trash` page under "SEE ALSO". Going, instead,

```
man 1 restore-trash
```

shows you how this command works: you choose a number from the listed files. You don't need to know the restore location.

Without the `trash-cli` package I have no idea whether this is possible.

Comment: Very thanks for your answer!, as I to say, I rescue it with `ddrecue`, but I'll save your answer on my computer as **firs aid** when next time does the same mistake ...

Comment: Umm... I think you'll find that `ddrescue` does NOT supply the original location where the file was when it was sent to trash. So my answer is the normal way to restore.  `ddrescue` would be the "first aid", or rather the "last resort".

Comment: yes, you have the right, therefore next time that I to delete a file on **caja**, I'll use your recommendations...

Answer (score 1):

To restore a deleted file from trash just follow these steps:

1. install trash-cli package
2. Just head over to the directory from where you deleted the file
3. Run command trash-restore, it will give you the list of deleted items from the current folder .now choose the index no of the deleted file you want to restore and you are all done.

Just head over to the directory from where you deleted the file